# How to pass C# class object as parameter to a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have an order class Orders.cs:

```
public class Orders
{
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string OrderScope { get; set; }
}
```

This `Orders` class above is exactly the same as my database `Orders` table.

Also I have a class which contains methods for working with orders table with ADO.NET:

```
public class OrdersData
{
        public static int InsertOrder(Orders Order)
        {
            // Create the SQL Query for inserting a new order
            string sqlQuery = String.Format("Insert into Orders (OrderScope, PersonId , EquipmentId) Values('{0}', '{1}', '{2}');"
            + "Select @@Identity", Order.OrderScope, Order.PersonId, Order.EquipmentId);

            // Create and open a connection to SQL Server
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();

            // Create a command object
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);

            // Execute the command to SQL Server and return the newly created ID
            int newOrderID = Convert.ToInt32((decimal)command.ExecuteScalar());

            // Close and dispose
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();

            // Set return value
            return newOrderID;
        }
}
```

As you can see, the `InsertOrder` method takes an `Orders` object as a parameter. 
Now I need to create a stored procedure in my db which inserts a new order like in `InsertOrder` method.

I've googled this but I only can find some tutorials on passing multiple parameters to a stored procedure but that's not exactly what I need to do.

Comment: You use [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/)

Comment: With "low-level" ADO.NET and raw SQL (`SqlCommand`), there is **no way** you can pass an "object" as parameter. ORM's like Dapper or Entity Framework will allow this, so you don't have to deal with all the details of setting all the individual values in ADO.NET/SQL anymore.

Comment: @marc_s Well, technically, you could pass a data table or an `IEnumerable<T>` as a table valued parameter, but that would be silly.

Answer (score 0):

At our company, we use a framework that works only with objects being passed in and out of SQL Server databases. However, this requires a framework (ours is based on the Pconsoft libraries) that converts the input object into stored procedure parameters and converts result sets into a single object or a collection of objects. There might be other frameworks out there that will do similar tasks.

However, if you are just trying to send in object data in a limited fashion, you can do it by serializing the object as XML and passing it into an SQL Stored Procedure (as a parameter) that reads and expands that XML. You can do this by converting the XML to a string and passing it in that way, but we prefer to convert the data in .NET to the SqlXml data type, and accept it as an XML data type parameter in the stored procedure in SQL Server. Hopefully this will help.